Would a VACUUM FULL save space before a SET TABLESPACE?
In a postgres database, a VACUUM FULL on a table will reclaim any free space by completely re-writing the table.
Also, moving a table from one tablespace to another (using ALTER TABLE... SET TABLESPACE) will re-write the table (assuming the other tablespace is on another disc).
So, is there anything to be gained by doing both VACUUM FULL and SET TABLESPACE on the same table? or in other words, will the VACUUM FULL recover any space that altering the tablespace wouldn't do anyway?
This is related to this post, but it's nearly ten years old and refers to an obsolete version of postgres.

I had a case in PostgreSQL13 where I expected altering PK from int to bigint to remove bloat since it's rewriting the whole table. But the bloat was still there even after rewrite. So there could be some difference in VACUUM FULL and rewrite issued by other commands. Did you test your case?
